# CorePlot and Parse compatibility?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, core-plot

I am adding CorePlot library into an app project using Parse as database. I followed the setup steps in CorePlot documentation but came across about 50 error messages, and I found the error messages occurs when I add `-ObjC` to other linker flags after adding other necessary files of CorePlot.

Searching through the web, found 2 threads in Google discussion groups:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/coreplot-discuss/lmiw_kS2uOA
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/ya2gnFB80to

I do not quite understand what does it mean to use `-force_load` instead of using `-ObjC`. Does it mean I just type `-force_load` or `-ObjC -force_load` in other linker flags? I have tried both but I ended up with the same error message:

> ld: file not found: -fobjc-arc
>   
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Core Plot are you using? What method did you use to add it to your app (precompiled static library, dependent project, CocoaPods)?

Comment: I came across the same issue. I used static library, Core Plot 1.6. Tried for a few hours and finally gave up. Really hope someone can help us with this. =\